# What're the appropriate icon/buttons/image sizes for iOS app development?

Tags: ios, user-interface, screen-resolution, image-size

According to the [Icon and Image Sizes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) of official Human Interface Guideline,

3 sizes of the same image are required to be included for different devices' resolution.

Take a look at the Tool bar & Navigation bar icon requirements,
required resolution for @3x image (iPhone6/6s plus) is 66x66 pixels, for 2x (iPhone 4s/5/5s/6/6s, iPad Pro/Air...) is 44*44 pixels.

How is the required resolution for iPad (@2x) lower than iPhone 6/6s plus(@3x)?

@2x images are displayed in low quality on iPad devices, shouldn't it be the highest resolution requirement for big screen devices?

Comment: It has nothing to do with screen size. It's all about density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the pixel density of the "plus" phones is a ridiculously high [400 pixels per inch](https://www.tekrevue.com/retina-display-comparison/). iPad displays are around 250 pixels per inch.